# Mongoose Server callback loop

Tags: c++, http, https, mongoose-web-server

After looking for a C library that implemented a web server, I was taught about Mongoose. I have actually made it work through several examples that make the call to the callback function that actually treats the incoming and outgoing data. I am using on Windows, compiling and debugging with Visual Studio 2008.

I called it session and it follows:

```
int CHttpsCom::Session( void )
{

  struct mg_context *ctx;

  const char *options[] = {
    "listening_ports", "443s",
#ifdef _DEBUG
    "ssl_certificate", "c:\\temp\\cert.pem",
#else
    "ssl_certificate", "cert.pem",
#endif
    NULL
  };

  ctx = mg_start( &callback, NULL, options );

  if( !ctx )
    return 1;

  //getchar();  // Wait until user hits "enter"
  while ( LeaveIt == false );

  Sleep(3500);// without this it won't work

  mg_stop( ctx ); 

  return 0;

}
```

100% of the examples I have noticed most examples use getchar to synchronize the end of the session with the ending if the callback execution. I have this LeaveIt flag that is set after I get a post message. If I don't use the Sleep above, I get a deadlock internal to the library. Is there any better way of handling this wait for the the callback ending ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
while ( LeaveIt == false );

Sleep(3500);// without this it won't work
```

By this (at worst you'll save CPU consumption):

```
while (!LeaveIt)
{
    Sleep(500);
}
```

Comment: I second this answer.